# Best way to access Qt ui from other class

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I'm trying to access UI from a class outside of my main windows class
I've tried some ways like declare my function in the main window heder, and then use the main window in those function in CPP files to access the UI (**But its clearly not a good way**)
so I think it's better to use signal and slot for send data from other class to the main class
I'm doing it in this way, I show my codes below

---

in my worker header, I declare all my needed functions in `public` and also create a signal for fire `updateUI` signal.

**worker.h**

```cpp
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    bool GetOSInfo();
    bool SetPrivilege(HANDLE hToken, LPCTSTR Privilege, BOOL bEnablePrivilege);
    void DisplayError(LPCSTR szAPI);
    int EscalatePrivilege();
    bool CreateRemoteThread_Type1(LPCSTR ID, HANDLE hProcess);

signals:
    void updateUI(const int error, const QString text, const QString value);

};
```

in my main window header create a slot for receiving a fired signal from the worker class

**mainwindow.h**

```cpp
private slots:
    void Reciver(const int error, const QString text, const QString value);
```

after that In CreateRemoteThread.cpp (I need CreateRemoteThread_Type1 function from this file) I'm emit a signal

**CreateRemoteThread.cpp**

```cpp
bool Worker::CreateRemoteThread_Type1(LPCSTR ID, HANDLE hProcess) {
//some code
    emit updateUI(0, "text", Null);
}
```

and finally, I receive a fired signal in my *mainwindow.cpp*

**mainwindow.cpp**

```cpp
Worker worker; //global

Mainwindow::Mainwindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
        
    QObject::connect(&worker, &Worker::updateUI, this, &mainwindow::Reciver);
}

//some code

void mainwindow::Reciver(const int error, const QString text, const QString value)
{
    ui.textEdit->append(text);
}
```

it is working well and slot Trigger when signal fired
And another thing I think I should mention is that I use this signal and slot to only show some log text in main gui from my functions
I have some question about this code:

1. It is a good way to access the main window UI from another class?
2. as you can see I declare Worker globally in my *mainwindow.cpp* `(Worker worker)` the reason is I need it multiple times in multi-function in my *mainwindow.cpp*, but I don't like to use it globally... what best way to avoid it? (or maybe it's ok?)

and at the end any better Idea for using the UI from other class are welcome
Thank you for taking the time to read this text

---

as Aziuth Recomended I post a working cod in [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), here is a link to it [Best way to access Qt ui from other class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254443/best-way-to-access-qt-ui-from-other-class)

Comment: Opinion based. I'd first consider if you truly want your new class to be a child of `QObject`. That is more of a design question. Usually I have my computative backend not being derived from that, but classes that are inteded to work closely with Qt classes I do derive from them. Another aspect is that slot communication can be hard to debug. If you directly invoke a method from a class somewhere, you know how data flows. If you emit a signal, you have to check with what it is connected first. I'd do that when the layout is kind of similar and the connection is intuitive.

Comment: Global variables should be avoided if not constant. Wouldn't make it a Singleton either. Why don't you simply either make it a member of your main window or have your main window have a member that is some kind of pointer to it (probably `std::weak_ptr`)?

Comment: @Aziuth thank you for help and advises, so you think its better to add all my needed function to main window class itself and use UI in them directly? in start I wanted to do same, but some one said its better to keep GUI stuff and logical work separate, it's way easier for work with if i can to access UI directly from my functions

Comment: I think I understand you wrong  you talking about global variables, but i talk about function declaration

Comment: And another thing I think I should mention is that I use this signal and slot to only show some log text in main gui from my functions

Comment: The global variables are about your second question. In general, here is the thing - you asking your questions quite generally. I don't think there is a general answer. My advice is that you write something and then put it on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). And not the snippets above, I'm talking about a first working version of what you want to do. That's basically what that site made for. Just be aware that people will pick basically every single line you wrote apart.

Comment: @Aziuth hi and thanks for advise, as you recommended I post a working cod in CodeReview, and ask if its the best way or not. here is a link to it [Best way to access Qt ui from other class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254443/best-way-to-access-qt-ui-from-other-class)